# How not to load a file repeatedly?

Tags: input

I created a file `version.tex` with a `git log` message. This `.tex`-file is then included in my `main.tex` file like this:

```
\renewcommand{\footsnippy}{%
  Author Name,
  Title of my Book,  %
  \input{version}
}
```

because `footsnippy` is used by the document class to print the current date, author, title -- and now the git log -- onto each page.

But: LaTeX now is slowed down quite a bit, because it seems that the `\input` is now executed on *every page*. Hrm...

Look:

```
...
) [11] (./version.tex) [12] (./version.tex) [13] (./version.tex) [14]
(./version.tex) [15] (./version.tex) [16] (./version.tex) [17] (./version.tex)
[18] (./version.tex) [19] (./version.tex) [20] (./version.tex) [21]
(./version.tex) [22]) (./wikitex/00Vorwort.tex (./version.tex) [23]
(./version.tex) [24]) (./version.tex) [25] (./wikitex/teil01beginn.tex
(./version.tex) [26]
...
```

Is there any way I can circumvent that the file is read again and again?

Comment: You can save the input in a savebox.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks, got it working with this tip and googling. If you make it an answer,  you have the chance to get the credit for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load the file just once, the key is the `catchfile` package:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\gitinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcsname gitinput#1\endcsname
  \else
    \CatchFileDef\temp{#1}{}
    \global\expandafter\let\csname gitinput#1\endcsname\temp
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \csname gitinput#1\endcsname
}

\renewcommand{\footsnippy}{%
  Author Name,
  Title of my Book,
  \gitinput{version}
}
```

When you do `\gitinput{version}` the first time, the macro `\gitinputversion` is defined, expanding to the contents of the `version.tex` file. Then the `\gitinputversion` command is performed at any call of `\gitinput{version}`; but the file is not read in more than once.

This has an advantage over setting a reusable box, because the present method will respect the surrounding font shape and font size conditions.

Comment: Indeed "respect the surrounding font shape and font size conditions" is *the* advantage. I use the savebox in this specific instance now, but I can imagine, I need your solution another time. Since I had to write the other answer myself, there is no doubt, that your answer is the one to be accepted :-)

Answer (score 4):

Without any package I used a `savebox` as @MarcoDaniel suggested.

```
\newsavebox{\tversion}
\savebox{\tversion}{{\tiny\input{version}}}

\renewcommand{\footsnippy}{%
    Author Name,
    Title of my Book,
    \usebox{\tversion}
}
```

As you can see, I had to add the formatting `\tiny` into the savebox, because the box itself is saved, not only the loaded file content. This means, that the formatting that was previously done inside the `footsnippy` command on the `\input{version}` text does not apply anymore with savebox. So i have to apply it inside the savebox.